# Backbone.js - Scope collection of objects to only a certain project

Tags: ruby-on-rails, backbone.js, coffeescript

I am using backbone.js with a rails backend.

I have a collection of objects:

```
class D3.Collections.ResourceInstances extends Backbone.Collection
  url: '/project/'+D3.projectId+'/resource_instances'
```

I am trying to scope resource_instances to the current project of the user. In my Rails view I am setting projectId on D3:

```
<%= javascript_tag do %>
  $(document).ready( function() {
    D3.projectId = <%= @project.id %>;
  });
<% end %>
```

When I call `resources = new D3.Collections.ResourceInstances()` in my browser console `resources.url` is `"/project/undefined/resource_instances"`. However, if I evaluate `'/project/'+D3.projectId+'/resource_instances'` in the console I get the expected `"/project/37/resource_instances"`. What is going on here? Why isn't the projectId defined in Collection?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The D3.projectId is not set until the document is ready which means the JavaScript will be loaded and interpreted before D3.projectId is defined.

You have two options:

**Remove the document ready** method wrapping the D3.projectId definition and make sure it is set **before** your javascripts are included on the page **or** make your url property a method like so:

```
class D3.Collections.ResourceInstances extends Backbone.Collection
  url: -> '/project/'+D3.projectId+'/resource_instances'
```

Comment: If I use the method (second) approach, Backbone will still handle that properly?

Comment: Yeah backbone uses underscore's result method that checks if url is a property or a method and gets result of either.